# Xcode 6 - iPhone crash log file

Tags: xcode, crash, xcode6

In previous versions of Xcode, I could import a .crash crash log file that was obtained by copying the crash report from the Diagnostics and Usage section on the iPhone.

In Xcode 6, I can't seem to find a way to do it in the Organizer.  I have the .crash file, but can't find anywhere to import it to symbolicate it.

Is it possible to do it without having the physical device connected in Xcode 6?

Comment: I am having the same problem with this. I can't find the library feature anywhere that used to let you do this.

Answer (score 15):

1. Open in Xcode - Window -> Devices.
2. Attach device if you don't have any attached - !important!
3. Click "View device logs" for your attached device.
4. Drag&Drop crash logs into device (or you can select All Logs and drop crash logs there).

You can see additional actions in context menu for each crash log like Re-symbolicate, Delete etc

Comment: why are they hiding an important tool like this so deeply?

Comment: Ummmm... because Apple?

Comment: Dropping crash logs doesn't work for me, neither at the `This Device` nor to the `All Logs` sections. They don't get added.

Comment: I don't have the phone that the crash log came from. How do I open the log in Xcode?

Comment: OMG. so hidden. You saved my day.

Comment: Rest is all fine, but I don't see the symbolicated logs, even after pressing the re-symbilicate button from context menu.

Comment: Just an addendum - the crash log MUST have the extension .crash for the drag-and-drop to work.  I was receiving a crash log via email, and couldn't get XCode to recognize the file until it had the correct extension

Comment: And an addendum - i think it only works if you have the same version of the app installed on that device. I managed to resymbolicate a crash log emailed from an iPhone 6Plus into my iPhone4s using this method. I did find I had to close and reopen Devices for it to pick it up.

Comment: What is the crash file's format, json or plist? @softwareevolved

Comment: @DawnSong - there's this thing called Google, that allows you to search for "ios crash log format".    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: In my iPhone's Settings->Privacy->Diagnostics, the crash log has a json header. However, in Xcode's Devices, no crash log has a json header. And testers in my team gives me crash logs in plist format. Now, I know there is no header. In the plist file, the value of the 'description' key is the whole crash log. Thank you a lot. @softwareevolved